# PXE boot: "mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: invalid cross-device link"

Tags: debian, initramfs, pxe

I am trying to set up a cluster of net-booted systems, and after initially succeeding, I've run into a strange problem, that I can't relate to what I have been doing recently.

I have been following these instructions: [RaspberryPi cluster](https://aoterodelaroza.github.io/devnotes/diskless-rpi-cluster/), skipping the parts that didn't relate to my situation:

- Step 6: Create the compute node image
- Step 9: Set up and test the chroot environment
- Step 12: Upgrade and install packages in the image
- Step 14: Modify the initramfs in the image to be able to network boot
- Step 16: Configure the FTP server
- Step 17: Configure SSH access to the compute nodes
- Step 20: Set up the NFS server

So far, so good - the system booted up, (I had already set up DHCP and TFTP for another purpose); the OS that is shared out is Debian 12, and I can log in as root on the console. This is the `menuentry` in GRUB:

```
menuentry 'Boot Debian 12' {
  set background_color=black
  linux /debian12/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-9-amd64 console=tty0 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs ro nfsroot=192.168.50.9:/image/debian12,vers=3,nolock panic=60 ipv6.disable=1 rootwait
  initrd /debian12/boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-9-amd64
}
```

The `fstab` in the boot image is empty, as I haven't got as far as setting that up; it hasn't been a problem until now.

Today, however, I run into this, when booting up ("mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: Invalid cross-device link"):

[image: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: Invalid cross-device link]

I can't for my life imagine how this comes about; nowhere in my notes, memory or imagination can I find any reference to mounting `/dev` on `/root/dev`, and even after unpacking the ramdiskfs (`/image/debian12/boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-9-amd64`), I can't find anything referring to something like this. So, the big question is 'how'?

***Edit1***

After digging a bit deeper, I found there is a script, `init`, in the initrd:

```
unpack the initrd:

root@vogon:~/test# unmkinitramfs /image/debian12/boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-9-amd64 .
root@vogon:~/test# ll 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 26 12:28 early/
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 26 12:28 main/
root@vogon:~/test# ll main
total 28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jun 26 12:28 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun 26 12:28 conf/
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun 26 12:28 etc/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6556 Apr 10  2022 init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    7 Jun 26 12:28 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jun 26 12:28 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jun 26 12:28 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Jun 26 12:28 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 22 11:28 run/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    8 Jun 26 12:28 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 26 12:28 scripts/
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Jun 26 12:28 usr/
```

That seems to be where the attempts to mount several system directories under `/root` are; but I haven't yet found out how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this error happens when the initrd lacks the filesystem driver for the (real) root filesystem or something underneath that: a dm/loop device etc. from where the root image is [supposed to be] mounted. Given that you were setting up a cluster there, I guess you were trying to mount the root remotely, which can fail for lack of net fs (e.g. nfs) driver[s] in the initrd. (Initramfs shells generally lack `lsmod`, but you can check what kernel modules [and thus drivers] are loaded with `cat /proc/modules` too.) Also, wrong UUIDs [or for net fs, net paths] in the grub (or whatever boot loader you're using) config can lead to the same error. As for checking the net paths, try to mount them manually from the initramfs prompt.